# css first and last doesn't work in selenium rc

Tags: python, css, selenium, selenium-rc

I have a query:

```
x= sel.is_element_present("css=div#result form[class*='result']:last")
```

gives me false, but this:

```
    <td>storeElementPresent</td>
<td>css=div#result form[class*='result']:last</td>
<td>selFlightsFormCurrent</td>
```

gives me true.

Is there any bug with it?

Comment: what version of the server are you using?

Comment: selenium-server-1.0.3. python version is 2.7 ,System windows xp, and ff 3.6.13

Comment: the selectors are `:first-child` and `:last-child`, not `:first` and `:last`.  At least this is true in the [CSS-3 Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/) -- not really sure about selenium specifically.

Comment: starting in selenium server 2.0a6 or so we switched to using Sizzle for the css library so :first and :last are valid -- just not with this version of the server. Grab 2.0b1 or 2.0b2 and give it another try.

Comment: I'm using now 2.0b2 and it works :) thanks a lot Adam

Comment: @adam goucher: You should copy your comment into an answer. It's perfectly valid, and better than the one currently there (though that one has a point, too).

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider using an XPath selector to get your first and last items. I've found XPath to be a bit more flexible than CSS.